# How to select a free function with std::conditional

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have quite a lot of pairs of free functions of the form below from some C library:

```
void dvecse(int, double, double *, int);
void svecse(int, float,  float *,  int);
```

I want to wrap them in C++ such that I can call one function, e.g. `vecse`, and let the compiler figure out which of the two to call.

I tried to achieve this with `std::enable_if`, but I don't think it's meant for that (on/off semantics instead of selection) and something like below obviously doesn't compile because of redeclaration:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, double>::value> vecse = dvecse;

template <typename T>
std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value> vecse = svecse;
```

Also, I tried `std::conditional` which seems to work with types only and not with free functions (a design with functors would be an alternative, but I'd be wrapping all the free functions in function objects).

What would be a concise way of achieving function selection at compile time?

Comment: `enable_if` is not for cases like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need templates when overloading will do:

```
void vecse(int a, double b, double* c, int d) { dvesce(a,b,c,d); }
void vecse(int a, float b, float* c, int d) { svecse(a,b,c,d); }
```

PS: I'd suggest you to use meaningful names. I had to triple check for typos.

PPS: When you need to do something different for each type (here: calling the respective method), you usually do not gain much from using templates.

Comment: This has one disadvantage compared to an approach like above (presuming it's possible): if the signature of the underlying function changes, I have to change it in all `vecse` declarations as well.

Comment: @Nibor not sure, but if a parameter type changes I'd consider this as a breaking change and I'd maybe prefer my code to break with a compiler error rather than silently

Comment: @Nibor I think you could write a wrapper functor that (via template magic) offers the right overloads of `operator()` but I doubt that it is worth the effort

Comment: @Nibor I'd go further that this answer, to say that you shouldn't have functions named `dvesce` and `svesce`. I think you should name them both `vesce`. If you're passing `float`s or `double`s the compiler will pick the appropriate overload.